# Using an AirPlay target screen as the only display for a Mac Mini (without VNC)

Tags: macos, mac-mini, airplay

I just aquired a Mac Mini with M2 processor. It so happens that I have a windows PC with a built in 27" 4K display that I would like to use as a screen.

Using a full version of [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/), I am able to connect the Mac to the screen once I am logged in, by connecting to the AirPlay server. However, **is there a way to pair them permanently, so that the Mac will automatically use a selected AirPlay target as its screen, allready during the login screen?**

I know this can be done in a "remote desctop" way using [RealVNCViewer](https://www.howtogeek.com/214220/how-to-access-your-macs-screen-from-windows-and-vice-versa/) but it would be cool if a more native method like auto connecting to AirPlay before login existed.

Comment: AirPlay is terrible for a primary display. Low frame rate, lag, jitter, compression…these aren't things you want on a primary display. There's a reason HDMI is many, many gigabits per second.